# error: could not find or load main class First.class

Tags: java

I have made program in java using netbeans. it is located in d`:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src\firstapp`. its name is `First.java`. it is running successfully and showing output in `netbeans IDE.` but when i m trying to run it through **cmd** its showing the above error.

**PATH** is set to `c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin`
**classpath** is set to `.`

i have also tried setting **classpath** to `c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin` but there was no change in the error..

`javac First.java` is running and CLASS file is getting created in the same folder where the program is.

please help me out.. i cannot debug it..

Comment: It's not clear where your class is but your classpath must point to the directory containing First.class.

Comment: did you use `package somepackage;` declaration in your class First?

Comment: Certainly a package problem.. Try compiling it using : - `javac -d . First.java` and see where your class file is created..

Comment: @dystroy: you mean to say that my classpath must be set to d:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src\firstapp.. because class file is getting created here only.

Comment: @user1724991.. Yeah.. Classpath contains the path till your class file.

Comment: @dystroy : not necessary. If you are running class from directory where it exists.

Comment: @user1724991.. See my post.. Probably it would be clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-** If you are able to create a .class file then i think you have successfully installed your Java

**Tip:**

Always do a `java -version` on the command prompt, and if it returns with the version of JDK installed on your system, then you have successfully installed your Java.

**-** Now i will advice you to do this from the same directory where you class file is located to execute the file.

`java First`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing execution using package name.

You would be executing main class from src directory as :

```
D:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src> java firstapp.First
```

Comment: no no.. i m executing it from D:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src\firstapp> javac First.java is successful. and CLASS file is getting created..

Comment: @RohitJain: when i m doing javac -d . First.java ,its creating another folder with name firstapp inside firstapp(where program resides).. and there lies First.class

Comment: @user1724991 : well you have compiled it from package `firstapp`. If you want to compile it from `src`, use `javac firstapp\First.java`. But it will place `.class` file in same directory as source.

Comment: @user1724991.. Yes it will create that folder.. That's the folder for the package.. Now you can run it as you were doing from the same folder as `.java` file..

Comment: @NandkumarTekale.. (S)He will anyhow have to move it to a directory for the package.. This is not the right way to compile a java file under a package..

Comment: @RohitJain: 
D:\sudhanshu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FirstApp\src\firstapp>javac First.java

D:\sudhanshu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FirstApp\src\firstapp>java First.class
Error: Could not find or load main class First.class

D:\sudhanshu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FirstApp\src\firstapp>

Comment: it still fails... can you plz elaborate what you are trying to say tht what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

If your package is : `somepackage`,

And you have saved your `.java` file at: `d:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src\firstapp`

then in command prompt, go to the above directory and compile using: -

```
javac -d . First.java   // Don't use javac First.java
```

Then your class file will be created inside the folder `somepackage` inside the above path..
i.e. your class file will be at `d:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src\firstapp\somepackage\First.class`

Then you should go at the directory where your `.java.` file is saved, and run as: -

```
java First
```

From `d:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src\firstapp` directory..

**If you want to run this class file from anywhere: -**

Add `d:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\Firstapp\src\firstapp` directory in your classpath..

Note: - You need to add the directory containing your package directory to classpath..

Comment: d:\sudhanshu\documents\netbeansprojects\FirstApp\src\firstapp\First.java

Comment: @user1724991... Now, is there any package declaration for your .java file?? If yes, then compile using `javac -d . First.java` from your `firstapp` directory.. If not, then compile using `javac First.java`